# How to include the outside legend into the generated file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, png, legend

I am plotting many lines on several axes, so I have a several fairly busy plots, thus I need to place the legend *outside* of the figure:

```
import numpy as np
nrows = 4
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 2*nrows))
axes = fig.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=1)
names = [f"name-{n}" for n in range(10)]
for ax in axes:
    for n in names:
        ax.plot(np.arange(10),np.random.normal(size=10),label=n)
fig.tight_layout()
axes[0].legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1,0,1,1))
```

which produces something like

[image: sample chart]

However, when I save the figure using `fig.savefig("test.png")`, I get this:

[image]

note the missing legend.

How do I save the figure so that the legend is included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `plt.subplots_adjust` and you can customize the space around the figure. Here I just used `plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)` but you can adjust all the settings (including `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `hspace`, `wspace`)

```
import numpy as np
nrows = 4
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 2*nrows))
axes = fig.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=1)
names = [f"name-{n}" for n in range(10)]
for ax in axes:
    for n in names:
        ax.plot(np.arange(10),np.random.normal(size=10),label=n)
fig.tight_layout()
axes[0].legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1,0,1,1))

fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.80)
fig.savefig("test.png")
```

Saved image:

[image]

Comment: why 0.8? how did you settle on this number?

Comment: It's just based on a fraction of the figure width. No method on settling on that number other than looking at the saved figure and seeing if the legend was contained and changing it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to tell `tight_layout()` not to use the full width. That leaves enough room for your legend. I'm not sure if there's a way measure the width of your legend in code, but I experimentally found this fits your legend:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
nrows = 4
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 2*nrows))
axes = fig.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=1)
names = [f"name-{n}" for n in range(10)]
for ax in axes:
    for n in names:
        ax.plot(np.arange(10),np.random.normal(size=10),label=n)
fig.tight_layout(rect=(0, 0, 0.84, 1))
axes[0].legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1,0,1,1))

fig.savefig("test.png")
```

After some experimentation, though, it seems like simplifying the call to `legend()` tells `tight_layout()` about the legend and to leave room for it. Now, making the names longer automatically makes the plots smaller so that everything fits.

There was a problem with `tight_layout()` leaving gaps between subplots, because the legend was taller than the subplot. We put a single entry in the legend, call `tight_layout()`, then put all the entries in the legend. The legend extends below the bottom of the first subplot, but that's what we want.

If the names are different lengths, you'd have to do some more trickery to use the longest name instead of the first name or split all the entries across all the subplots before calling `tight_layout()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
nrows = 4
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 2*nrows))
axes = fig.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=1)
names = [f"name-{n}" for n in range(10)]
for ax in axes:
    for n in names:
        ax.plot(np.arange(10),np.random.normal(size=10),label=n)

# Create a legend with only one entry, so tight_layout doesn't stretch down.
handles, labels = axes[0].get_legend_handles_labels()
axes[0].legend(handles[:1], labels[:1], bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
fig.tight_layout()

# Use all the entries without worrying about expanding below the subplot.
axes[0].legend(handles, labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))

fig.savefig("test.png")
```

Comment: `measure the width of your legend in code` - this is the question! ;-)

Comment: Looks like simplifying `legend()` makes everything fit, @sds.

Comment: when the `legend` is called before `tight_layout`, the space between the individual axes becomes humongous.

Comment: I found a fix for that space, @sds. Add a single legend entry, call `tight_layout()`, then put in the full legend.